# tasm: operand type does not match

Tags: assembly, tasm

```
.model small
.stack
.data
    buff label byte
    maxchar dw 50
    readchar dw 0
    name1 db 48 dup(0)
    m1 db 10,13,"enter name: $"
    m2 db 10,13,"your name is: $"
.code
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    lea dx, m1
    mov ah, 09
    int 21h
    lea dx, buff
    mov ah, 10
    int 21h


    mov ah,0
    mov al, readchar
    add ax, 2
    mov si, al
    mov buff[si],24H ;ascii code for $ to terminate string
    lea dx, m2
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    lea dx, name1
    mov ah, 09
    int 21h

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
end
```

Comment: I don't see a question here...

Comment: Also, when posting about an error message you should point out the line(s) that the error message(s) correspond to.

Answer (score 3):

The *operand type does not match* error comes from trying to move

- a word sized variable into a byte sized register (`mov al, readchar`)
- a byte sized register into a word sized register (`mov si, al`)

To solve these issues you have to consider what the next data definitions really represent.

```
buff label byte
 maxchar dw 50
 readchar dw 0
 name1 db 48 dup(0)
```

These 4 lines of code together are the structure that is used by the DOS input function 0Ah. It expects **bytes** in the 1st and 2nd fields!
So to get rid of the first problem change this into

```
buff label byte
 maxchar  db 50
 readchar db 0
 name1    db 48 dup(0)
```

To correct the second problem just write `mov si, ax` which is what you intended anyway.

As a bonus, why don't you put the label *name1* to work? It will save you the `add ax, 2` instruction.

```
mov ah, 0
mov al, readchar
mov si, ax
mov name1[si], '$'
```

As a second bonus, you could use the BX register in stead of SI and save yet another instruction.

```
mov bh, 0
mov bl, readchar
mov name1[bx], '$'
```

Answer (score 2):

First mistake:

```
readchar dw 0
...
mov al, readchar
```

`readchar` is defined as WORD ("dw" = "**d**ata **w**ord", some say "**d**efine **w**ord". A word has a size of 16 bits. `AL` is an 8-bit-register. You cannot store a 16-bit word into an 8-bit register.

Second mistake:

```
mov si, al
```

`SI` is a 16-bit register, `AL` is an 8-bit register. You cannot copy an 8-bit register into a 16-bit register.