# Moving the contents of a register into a variable

Tags: assembly, fasm

I would need to move the contents of a register into a variable.
This works:

```
mov [a], 8      ; it's a random value (8), just for example.
```

However, this does not work:

```
mov eax, 8
mov [a], eax
```

I have searched the [documentation](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#2.1.1), but found nothing that matches my needs. I therefore turn to you, hoping to find a solution to this "problem".

PS: I've also tried to swap the register/variable values, but this can't work, since my variable has an unknown value (-->''?').

Comment: That's the right syntax; how did you declare `a`?  And is there an error message?  "doesn't work" is not a sufficient description for a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterCordes: I have declared' a' as follows: "a dw ?". The error message is:"operand sizes do not match". I see more or less what the message means, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `eax` is a 32-bit dword register, but your `a` is only a 16-bit `word`.  The assembler you're using associates a size with the symbol.  `mov [a], ax` would work, but you probably want `a dd ?`.

Comment: Near-duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169637/tasm-operand-type-does-not-match, but I can't find a 32-bit Q&A, or one using FASM.  The basic concept is the same, though: some assemblers, including FASM, give memory operands a default operand size based on their declaration.  (And even if they didn't, storing outside the `dw` you statically allocated is a bug if you didn't mean to do that.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Indeed, it works! Thank you very much. I know what I should be wary of for the rest, thank you again :)